# Integrating our web app to be used by MTM Microsoft test Manager

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, tfs, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

Hello I recently started with a new company that has developing a internal website for their finance and have been using TFS with Vis studio for quite some time. However they recently decided they wanted to expand into Automated UI testing and pair it with MTM for the QA dept.. The issue I am having is that the Microsoft Test Manager 2013 is not set up with a build to start using the automated/ lab environment features. Im at a loss of even where to go to merge that build with MTM so that I can then use the Test configuration tool to start creating a lab environment. Is there any documentation or resources that might help with the process to.

1)Create a build in MTM (using the web app I have in Vis studio)

2)Setup a Lab environment in MTM using the above build.

3)Being link my automated test cases(although that is pretty straight forward the above to I cannot seem to grasp.

Anything advice would be greatly!! appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Chris
(using Enterprise/Highest level of TFS and Vis stuido 2013)

Answer (score 0):

For (1) please refer the link from MSDN: [Working with builds in MTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gautamg/2010/07/19/working-with-builds-in-mtm/)

1. Go to Plan->Properties.
2. you can use the drop down to set the filter for the build (filter by build definition or build quality)
3. And finally use the Modify hyperlink to assign a new build.

For (2)(3) please refer the paragraph '*Build and install your application in a lab environment* ' **&** '*View and Update the Test Results* ' from MSDN Link: [How to: Run Automated Tests In a Lab Environment Using Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553270(v=vs.110).aspx)